Short story about a scientist abducted and experimented on by aliens
It's a short fiction story in which a scientist was abducted by aliens and taken aboard their ship. The aliens wanted to know whether humanity was worthy of continued existence or not, so they took "the best sample" — a scientist — and conducted mental experiments on him, such as putting him through mazes and giving him erotic journals, in order to find out.
Initially, the man passed the tests, but then he started to get angry, feeling like a rat in a maze (he himself conducted experiments on rats), and began to do creepy things during the experiments, intentionally failing them. The aliens couldn't understand why he was doing this, but decided, based on this unknown behavior, that all of humanity should be destroyed.
I read this 12-15 years ago and I think this story was written in 50s or 60s — the golden age of American fiction stories. The story was both humorous and sad, with a lot of thinking by the captured scientist.

In roughly which year did you read this?

@LogicDictates I read it 12-15 years ago, and I think this story was written in 50s or 60s - golden age of american fiction stories? This story was both humorous and sad, with a lot of thinking by captured scientist.

"Finally, it becomes clear that aliens tested, whether they should live Earth let live or die." While editing your question, I wasn't sure what to make of this sentence. I think you meant that the aliens were testing whether they should let Earth live or die. Is that correct? And were they also testing whether or not they should live on Earth? Because you used the world "live" twice in that sentence, although one of the instances may have been a typo.

@LogicDictates Yeah, my English is not very cool, sorry. The aliens wanted to know, is humanity worth to continue to live. And they took "the best sample" - a scientist. They started to give him different tests, and initially he passed them well. But then he started to get angry, feeling himself like rat in the maze (he himself conducted experiments on rats). And he started to do creepy things during these experiments, and intentionally failed them. The aliens couldn't understand why he is doing this. So they decided that based on this unknown behavior, all humanity should be destroyed.

I've updated the question to include the additional info provided by your comments, and reworded things a little to improve the grammar. If anything reads incorrectly to you, though, or if you want to make any further changes or additions, please don't hesitate to edit the question again yourself.

@LogicDictates We solved this mystery, thank you very much!

"Learning Theory", a short story by James McConnell which was also the answer to the question Literature scene where a man determines he's in a space station by doing some tests; first published in If, December 1957, available at the Internet Archive. You may have read it in one of these compilations.

As I sit here in this small room and think about it, I am impressed most of all by the suddenness of the whole thing. At one moment I was out walking in the woods near my suburban home. The next thing I knew, here I was in a small, featureless room, naked as a jaybird, with only my powers of rationalization to stand between me and insanity.
[. . . .]
My means of escape is therefore obvious. He expects from me confirmation of all His pet theories. Well, he won't get it any more! I know all of His theories backwards and forwards, and this means I know how to give Him results that will tear His theories right smack in half!
[. . . .]
Verpk's vote notwithstanding, however, the rest of us are of the considered opinion that this whole new colony must be destroyed, and quickly. For it is obviously diseased or some such — as reference to our theories has proven. And should it by some chance come in contact with our other colonies, and infect our other animals with whatever disease or aberration it has, we would never be able to predict their behavior again. I need not carry the argument further, I think.
May we have your permission to destroy the colony as soon as possible, then, so that we may search out yet other colonies and test our theories against other healthy animals? For it is only in this fashion that science progresses.


That's it, thank you!

You're welcome!
